# My jQuery function doesn't work on Google Chrome on mobile

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile

I wrote a feature that must run on a site built in Wordpress, to show a chat of facebook messenger or a link that will refer me to the messenger app if on mobile.

I have tested the function on Chrome and FireFox on desktop and it works as expected.
On mobile however, it works only on firefox and the default browser of the devices but not on Chrome.

Below I enter the parts of the code involved.

```
<style>
.fb_reset {
    display: none;
}
.campaign-alert {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

```
<div id="fb-root" class="fb_reset">fb-chat</div>

<div id="campaign-alert" class="campaign-alert">fb-link</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',function () {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 990) {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "control facebook login";
        document.head.append(script);
        script.onload = function myFunction1() {
            document.getElementById('campaign-alert').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').style.display = 'block';
        }
        script.onerror = function myFunction2() {
            document.getElementById('fb-root').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('campaign-alert').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    else {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "control facebook login";
        document.head.append(script);
        script.onload = function myFunction1() {
            document.getElementById('campaign-alert').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').style.display = 'block';
        }
        script.onerror = function myFunction2() {
            document.getElementById('campaign-alert').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').style.display = 'block';
        }          
    }    
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "works correctly"?

Comment: That the script works, if the user is logged into Facebook on the used browser shows the div with id = fb-root. If instead the user is not logged into Facebook then he shows the div with id = campaign-alert

Comment: Can you please be more precise, and describe what happens when it doesn't work? By debugging your code if possible, for example by adding some `console.log` in your load and error functions to see if the events are triggered correctly? No errors in the browser console?

Comment: So, being both div in the display none, the script that I did puts in display block one of two depending on whether the user is logged into Facebook or not.
On Google chrome on mobile, neither div is displayed and no console errors are reported. The mistake is that at least one of the two divs should be seen